# If $x$ is a real number, show that there exists a Cauchy sequence of rationals $\{x_n\}$ representing $x$ such that $x_n < x$ for all n.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, cauchy-sequences

So here is my understanding. We know that every rational Cauchy sequence is bounded by some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all k, $|x_k|\leq N$. This is true because there exists m such that $|x_j-x_k|\leq1$ for $j,k\geq m$. We need to choose $N$ larger than $|x_m| + 1$.

So I think we could have that $x_k\leq N < x$ where $x$ is a real number.

But I am struggling to understand the relationship between $N$ and $x$. $N$ is just an upper bound based on the rational Cauchy sequence. $x$ is the equivalence class of the rational Cauchy sequence.

Comment: The best if you consider a specific example, say, how to construct a rational sequence that converges to $x=\pi$ from below?

Comment: @Berci So my confusion with trying an example would be if we have a sequence of rationals that converges to $\pi$ then $N$ can only be one digit of $\pi$. So if say $N$ is 4 then 4 is not less than 3.1415. Doesn't this break the condition I am trying to satisfy?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do with an integer bound.. The sequence would be bounded by $x$ itself by hypothesis, there's no need for another bound. Instead, you can specify a concrete sequence of rationals for e.g. $\pi$, and generalize for all real numbers.

Comment: I agree with Berci... I think there is something fundamental you’re missing. Perhaps your understanding of a Cauchy sequence?

Answer (score 1):

If a sequence converges in $\Bbb R$, then it is a Cauchy sequence.

So, for a given real $x$, you only have to show up a sequence $x_n$ of rationals, such that $x_n$ converges to $x$ from below.

**Hint:** You can choose $x_0, x_1,x_2,\dots \in\Bbb Q$ such that $0<x-x_n<\dfrac1{10^n}$.

Note that we are in the middle of constructing $\Bbb R$ from $\Bbb Q$ by *Cauchy competition*.
In general, a Cauchy sequence in a metric space is a sequence that 'wants to converge' to some point (which might not yet be present in the given space), and you can think of the Cauchy completion as simply filling in those 'holes'.

Comment: Hint: We know that if $0<x-x_n<\dfrac1{10^n}$ for each term in the sequence the difference between x and $x_n$ is getting more accurate. So we know $x_n > x_{n-1}$ So this implies that $x_1 < x_2 < .... < x_n < x$.  I might be messing up somewhere.

Comment: More on this hint:  $3,  3.1,  3.14,  3.141,  3.1415, ... $. This idea will take care of almost all reals $x$. A few rational $x$ will have to handled differently.